# How to make call from application

Tags: iphone, call

I want to take  button programmaticaly on first button my customer phone number will be display by tapping on the button then the user can call. In my tableview I have pasted following code

```
    marker *aMarker = [[marker alloc] init];
    PhoneLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 45, 30, 20)] autorelease];
    PhoneLabel.tag = kPhoneLabelTag;
    PhoneLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:PhoneLabel];

            PhoneB = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [PhoneB setTitle:aMarker.phone forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     PhoneB.frame = CGRectMake(15, 45, 200, 20);
    PhoneB.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    PhoneB.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:PhoneB];
    [cell addSubview:PhoneB]; 
    [GetDirectionB addTarget:self
                      action:@selector(phonecall:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

phonelabel is

```
                PhoneLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"p:%@"];
```

And on action

```
    -(void) phonecall:(id)sender
 {
marker *aMarker = [[marker alloc] init];
   tel:aMarker.phone;
  }
```

actually what logic should I applied so that when tapping the phone number button the same number will be called.  I am fetching "aMarker.phone" from the URL

Comment: I am parsing xml data from URL. and marker is the attribute of this. which contain information like phone number(aMarker.phone), address..ect

Answer (score 2):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://your number"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code to make a call.

```
-(void) phonecall:(id)sender
{
    NSString *number = @"123456..." // a phone nuber
    NSURL *phoneNumberURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",number]];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneNumberURL];
}
```

Comment: thats is also I tried before. But I am fetching phone number from  Url which is aMarker.phone. How can I assign the respective number in my tableview to call

Answer (score 0):

Following code is help for the call the phone which is written into label

```
if(![[UIDevice currentDevice].model isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
        {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:_ALERT_TITLE_MSG
                                                            message:@"This Phone is not support call facility"
                                                           delegate:self 
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];
        }else {
            if([lblTel.text length]>0)
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",lblTel.text,nil]]];
            else
                btnCallTapped.hidden=YES;

        }
```

Hope this code helping to you.